# Adding up Switch Case Values

Tags: javascript

This might be really simple, so I do apologise but I can't find any other question asking the same/similar. Here goes...

I am trying to find a way to add up all the case values used in each switch. So to calculate all the days of the week numbers and output the total numbers in the following

```
const getSleepHours = (day) => {
  switch(day) {
    case "Monday":
      return "8";
    break;

    case "Tuesday":
      return "9";
    break;
    
    case "Wednesday":
      return "9.5";
    break;
    
    case "Thursday":
      return "11";
    break;
    
    case "Friday":
      return "10.5";
    break;
    
    case "Saturday":
      return "13";
    break;
    
    case "Sunday":
      return "12";
    break;

    default:
      return "Not sure what day that is";
  }
};
```

So 8 + 9 + 9.5 + 11 + 10.5 + 13 + 12. So far I have tried things like the following

```js
const getSleepHours = (day) => {
  switch(day) {
    case "Monday":
      return "8";
    break;

    case "Tuesday":
      return "9";
    break;
    
    case "Wednesday":
      return "9.5";
    break;
    
    case "Thursday":
      return "11";
    break;
    
    case "Friday":
      return "10.5";
    break;
    
    case "Saturday":
      return "13";
    break;
    
    case "Sunday":
      return "12";
    break;

    default:
      return "Not sure what day that is";
  }
};


const getActualSleepHours = () => {
  const getSleepHours = ("Monday","Sunday");
    return getSleepHours();
};
console.log(getSleepHours());
```

Comment: @axtck where do I do that? I can't see any option to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could get the value for each day of the week, parse it as a `float` number. Then use those values to calculate the total (for example by using `reduce()`).

Also if you `return` out of a case, you don't need to `break` because it is no longer reachable.

```js
const getSleepHours = (day) => {
  switch (day) {
    case "Monday":
      return "8";
    case "Tuesday":
      return "9";
    case "Wednesday":
      return "9.5";
    case "Thursday":
      return "11";
    case "Friday":
      return "10.5";
    case "Saturday":
      return "13";
    case "Sunday":
      return "12";
    default:
      return "Not sure what day that is";
  }
};

const days = [
  "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", 
  "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday"
];

// get hours as float values
const sleepHours = days.map((d) => parseFloat(getSleepHours(d)));
// calculate the total
const sum = sleepHours.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0);

console.log(sum);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do without `switch-case`

```js
// 1️⃣
// Using Map object
// If you define duplicated key It won's so error
const sleepHours = new Map([
  ['monday', 8],
  ['tuesday', 9],
  ['wednesday', 9.5],
  ['thursday', 11],
  ['friday', 10.5],
  ['saturday', 13],
  ['sunday', 12],
])

let totalSleepHours = 0
for (const [key, value] of sleepHours) {
  totalSleepHours += value
}

// 2️⃣
// Using object
const sleepHours = {
  monday: 8,
  tuesday: 9,
  wednesday: 9.5,
  thursday: 11,
  friday: 10.5,
  saturday: 13,
  sunday: 12,
}

// If not provide initial value, array element at index 0 is used as the initial value
Object.values(sleepHours).reduce((acc, curr) => acc += curr)
```